# Workflow Approval by Email (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: workflow, approval

First I apologize.  I am very new to SharePoint.  Here is my problem:  I have created a form using InfoPath 2010 and have successfully published it.  What I would like to accomplish is to have the email that is sent for approval (to the approvers) to have the link to the approval task.  Because at the moment, the email is sent, folks have to click on the document, do their edits and then have to go to the workflow task to click on the approve or reject button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you look at this to create a custom designer workflow to review, edit the document and approve through workflow

https://sp.eota.energy.gov/sites/help/SiteAssets/SitePages/Creating%20a%20Custom%20Workflow/Creating%20a%20Custom%20Workflow.pdf